# Java list: get amount of Pairs with pairwise different Keys using lambda expressions

Tags: list, lambda, stream, hashmap

I have a list of key-value-pairs and I want to filter a list where every key parameter only occurs once.

So that a list of e.g. `{Pair(1,2), Pair(1,4), Pair(2,2)}` becomes `{Pair(1,2), Pair(2,2)}`.

It doesn't matter which `Pair` gets filtered out as I only need the size
(maybe there's a different way to get the amount of pairs with pairwise different key values?).

This all is again happening in another stream of an array of lists (of key-value-pairs) and they're all added up.

I basically want the amount of collisions in a hashmap.

I hope you understand what I mean; if not please ask.

```
public int collisions() {
    return Stream.of(t)
            .filter(l -> l.size() > 1)
            .filter(/*Convert l to list of Pairs with pairwise different Keys*/)
            .mapToInt(l -> l.size() - 1)
            .sum();
}
```

EDIT:

```
    public int collisions() {
    return Stream.of(t)
            .forEach(currentList = stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())) //Compiler Error, how do I do this?
            .filter(l -> l.size() > 1)
            .mapToInt(l -> l.size() - 1)
            .sum();
}
```

I overwrote the equals of Pair to return true if the Keys are identical so now i can use distinct to remove "duplicates" (Pairs with equal Keys).
Is it possible to, in forEach, replace the currentElement with the same List "distincted"? If so, how?

Regards,
Claas M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want the sum of amount of collisions per list or the amount of collisions in all list were merged into a single one before. I assumed the former, but if it's the latter the idea does not change by much.

This how you could do it with `Streams`:

```
int collisions = Stream.of(lists)
                       .flatMap(List::stream)
                       .mapToInt(l -> l.size() - (int) l.stream().map(p -> p.k).distinct().count())
                       .sum();
```

`Stream.of(lists)` will give you a `Stream<List<List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>` with a single element. 
Then you `flatMap` it, so that you have a `Stream<List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>`.

From there, you `mapToInt` each list by substracting its original size with the number of elements of unique Pairs by key it contained (`l.stream().map(p -> p.k).distinct().count()`).

Finally, you call sum to have the overall amount of collisions.

Note that you could use `mapToLong` to get rid of the cast but then `collisions` has to be a `long` (which is maybe more correct if each list has a lot of "collisions").

For example given the input:

```
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> l1 = Arrays.asList(new Pair<>(1,2), new Pair<>(1,4), new Pair<>(2,2));
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> l2 = Arrays.asList(new Pair<>(2,2), new Pair<>(1,4), new Pair<>(2,2));
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> l3 = Arrays.asList(new Pair<>(3,2), new Pair<>(3,4), new Pair<>(3,2));

List<List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> lists = Arrays.asList(l1, l2, l3);
```

It will output 4 as you have 1 collision in the first list, 1 in the second and 2 in the third.

Comment: (You answered while I edited my Question, adding a similar approach ;))

That looks really good! But "l" in "mapToInt" is of Type Pair (I guess because its flatmapped). I'm new to Java 8 so i couldnt resolve it myself.
Could you please help?

Comment: @ClaasM. Which implementation are you talking about? Your edit does not make much sense. `forEach` is a terminal operation, so you can't chain stream ops after calling it. And why do you want to use `forEach` anyway?

Comment: I mean your implementation.
And I want to use forEach to call distinct on Each list within the Array of Lists (of Pairs).
But your way looks better and I suppose you know more about streams etc. But I still couldnt get it to work because it says that l is of type Pair.

Comment: @ClaasM. No it should be a list. Assuming `lists` is a `List<List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>>`, `Stream.of(lists).flatMap(List::stream)` should give you a `Stream<List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>>`. Did you try it with my input data example?

Comment: Ah okay my mistake was that I used an Array of Lists instead of a List of Lists in Stream.of(...). Arrays.asList(myArray) fixed it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ClaasM. If you have an array of lists, you can omit the `flatMap(List::stream)` part, so `Stream.of(arrayOflists).mapToInt(..)`, although arrays with generics does not mix well (you should have a cast somewhere in your code)... I recommend using a List of Lists in first place.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a stream. Dump the list into a SortedSet with a custom comparator and diff the sizes:

```
List<Pair<K, V>> list; // given this

Set<Pair<K, V>> set = new TreeSet<>(list, (a, b) -> a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey())).size();
set.addAll(list);
int collisions = list.size() - set.size();
```

If the key type isn't comparable, alter the comparator lambda accordingly.

Comment: I think this task suits well for Stream. Furthermore, you can't specify a comparator and a collection in the `TreeSet` constructor, so you would have to do it in several steps.